# Confusion about function assign_add() in Tensor Flow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Could you please explain how a variable is updated with a new value in `tf.assign_add`? For example in the code below:

```
v = tf.get_variable("v", shape=(2, 1), initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
assignment = v.assign_add(2)
```

As the docstring of `assign_add`says argument `value` (which is `2` in this case) is to be added to the variable, I would expect `v` would be updated to an array [[2], [2]]. However, it returned

```
<tf.Variable 'v:0' shape=(2, 1) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[2.0000000e+00],
       [2.5789502e-09]], dtype=float32)>
```

If tensorflow only added `2` to the first element of `v`, why did the second element of `v` changed from `0` to `2.5789502e-09`?

Also, why do we have to use the expression `assignment = v.assign_add(2)`? Shouldn't it be `v = v.assign_add(2)`? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you not getting this error ? `ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 2 and 0 for 'AssignAdd' (op: 'AssignAdd') with input shapes: [2,1], [].`. But once you add like this `assignment = v.assign_add([[2],[1]])` it adds with the result `[[2.]
 [1.]]`

Comment: `v = v.assign_add([[2],[1]])` or `assignment = v.assign_add([[2],[1]])` adds an operation to the graph which is executed by `sess.run(assignment)` or `sess.run(v)`

Comment: Hi Mohan, thanks for your response. I didn't encounter any errors. In the first cell of my jupyterlab, I had this code `import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()`, then in the second cell, I had this code `v = tf.get_variable("v", shape=(2, 1), initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
print(v)` and in the third cell, this code `assignment = v.assign_add(2)
print(v)`. Also, I've just started reading about TensorFlow so I'm not sure what you meant by adds an operation to the graph. Which graph were you referring to?

Comment: You should read [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/graphs) and especially the section `Building a tf.Graph`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue described above was probably due to my installed tensorflow (version 1.12.0) that was likely corrupted. I uninstalled that version and fresh-installed tensorflow version 1.13.1. When I tried to run the code

```
v = tf.get_variable("v", shape=(2, 1), initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
assignment = v.assign_add(2)
```

then I got an error

```
InvalidArgumentError: Cannot update variable with shape [2,1] using a Tensor with shape [], shapes must be equal. [Op:AssignAddVariableOp]
```

Still, that does not fully explain why a corrupted tensorflow package could be able to perform the wrong operation (adding a scalar to an array of shape [2, 1]) at the first place. Moreover, I was able to train neural networks that used tensorflow backend and got results as expected.